# Generate duplicate class in GreenADO in android

Tags: android, database, error-handling, duplicates, greendao

why create duplicate  package when generate library greenado?

[image]

this is  generator

```
  private static final String PROJECT_DIR = System.getProperty("user.dir");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.greenado.db");
    schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault();

    addTables(schema);

    try{
        DaoGenerator n=new DaoGenerator();
  n.generateAll(schema,PROJECT_DIR+ "\\app\\src\\main\\java");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: your first sentence, particularly the second half, is not clear. please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean so we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using greenDAO 3.x Comment out the apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao' in your gradle file. Because it tries to generate the classes all over again.

So its either you use the greenDAO class generator or apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'. You can't use both in 3.x

Comment: How do I use the plugin only? I would like to remove the greenDAO class generator, then change the output of the plugin.